# How to configure hudson to ignore changes under specified SVN folders?

Tags: svn, hudson, ignore

I'm looking for a way to ignore changes under specified SVN folders in Hudson.
It's the same thing as exclude folders in TeamCity and filters in CC.Net.
I haven't found any configuration option under SVN GUI configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Hudson 1.334, in the build configuration, under Subversion -> Advanced..., there are three Exclusion boxes. If it's polling for changes, Hudson will ignore changes that match these exclusions when determining whether to trigger a build. You can tell Hudson to ignore files/folders (Excluded Regions), commits by particular users, or files with a particular subversion revprop.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by going to the workspace and running this command

```
svn propedit svn:ignore ./ignore_this_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

I have somewhat the same problem. Have a project that is organizationally under a main project, but is not to be build with the main project. It is sat up as a standalone build on Hudson.

Illustration:

- main

  - sub1
  - sub2
  - sub3

So I thought that I could just add "/trunk/sub3/.*" in the "Excluded regional" field under the "Source Code Management" in the Hudson? But this does not seem to have any effect. 
The main project builds when I do changes under the sub3 project. Thought this was the intention of the "exluded regions" field.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Not sure why my ignores are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you add to the **Excluded Regions** field make sure has the same path as in the changes log. for example if in the changes you have:

> /branches/Update3/trunk/build/Win32/Release.exe

then use the very same path in the **Excluded Regions** too:

> /branches/Update3/trunk/build/Win32/Release.exe

I think the explanation here it that you have to use the path starting from the svn repository name and not the one related to the working copy of the repo.