# How to exclude a file\folder from SVN monitoring in Jenkins build

Tags: .net, svn, jenkins

Jenkins version: 1.587

I'm using Jenkins to do .Net solution build and I want to exclude a file from the SVN monitoring for changes - so if this file\folder changes it DOES NOT trigger a new build.

SVN url (folder) being monitored - https://XXXX/branches/ICE_New_Build/References

Under this folder there is a 'Foo\Bar 1.0' I want this pulled from SVN when built, but if a the contents of the folder changes I don't want it to trigger a new build.

I've managed to build the solution perfectly fine and I'm able to setup the 'monitoring for changes', I just want to be able to exclude sub-folders from the 'monitoring for changes'.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure hudson to ignore changes under specified SVN folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826638/how-to-configure-hudson-to-ignore-changes-under-specified-svn-folders)

Comment: as far i can see this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **Job Configuration**, under **Source Code Management** section, click the **<kbd>Advanced...</kbd>** button.

This opens up **Excluded Regions** field. Click the question **<kbd>?</kbd>** icon next to it for more information. In general, you will add the excluded region as:
`/branches/ICE_New_Build/References/Foo/Bar 1.0/.*`
or if you don't want any mergeinfo triggers on that folder:
`/branches/ICE_New_Build/References/Foo/Bar 1.0.*`

Note the pattern is relative from the root of your repo